# Поясните, пожалуйста.

Tags: орфография

Все орфографии в словах огорчен и потрясен.

Answer (score 2):

Это Вы поясните, что же Вам нужно. Может, назвать орфограммы? Тогда здесь это безударные гласные в корнях и приставках, Ё после шипящих в причастии, одна Н в кратких причастиях.

Answer (score 0):

Все орфографии и пунктуации)))))